# Using cURL to create and download custom reports

Tags: php, curl, character-encoding, query-string, libcurl

I'm trying to use cURL to login to a secure site, create a custom report which contains financial data, and download it to my machine. I've determined that the remote login process is working. The problem lies with the POST parameters that I am using to create and download the report. I've been trying to get this to work for about a week now, and I'm having no luck.

Basically, this works for logging in (simplified):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://manager.myurl.com/login.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'partnerName='.$partner.'&vendorName='.$username.'&password='.$password);
```

But the same process for downloading the custom report does not work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://manager.myurl.com/customReport.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $downloadpost);
```

The $downloadpost variable (a multi-dimensional array) is created this way:

```
$today = Date('d');
$month = Date('m');
$year = Date('Y');
$pmonth = $month - 3;
$pyear = $year;

if ($pmonth < 1) {
   $pmonth = 12 + $pmonth;
   $pyear = $year - 1;
}

$downloadpost=http_build_query(
    array(
        'newTemplateName' => '',
        'dateRange' => 'Custom',
        'fromMonth' => $pmonth,
        'fromDate' => $today,
        'fromYear' => $pyear,
        'fromHour' => '00',
        'fromMinute' => '00',
        'fromSecond' => '00',
        'toMonth' => $month,
        'toDate' => $today,
        'toYear' => $year,
        'toHour' => '23',
        'toMinute' => '59',
        'toSecond' => '59',
        'timezone' => 'U.S. Eastern',
        'cardTypes' => 'C-5,C-4,C-2,C-1,C-0',
        'transactionTypes' => 'S,D,O,A,F,C,V',
        'userName' => 'MyUserName', 
        'minAmount' => '0.00',
        'maxAmount' => '10000.00',
        'resultOption' => 'Approvals Only',
        'displayColumns' => array(
            'Transaction ID',
            'ABA Routing Number',
            'AVS Streeth Match',
            'AVS Zip Match',
            'Account Number',
            'Amount',
            'Authcode',
            'Batch ID',
            'Billing Address',
            'Billing City',
            'Billing Company Name',
            'Billing Country',
            'Billing Email',
            'Billing First Name',
            'Billing Last Name',
            'Billing State',
            'Billing Zip',
            'CSC Match',
            'Comment1',
            'Comment2',
            'Customer Code',
            'Duty Amount',
            'Expires',
            'Freight Amount',
            'Invoice Number',
            'Original Transaction ID',
            'PayPal Email ID',
            'PayPal Fees',
            'Purchase Order',
            'Response Msg',
            'Result Code',
            'Shipping Address',
            'Shipping City',
            'Shipping Email',
            'Shipping First Name',
            'Shipping Last Name',
            'Shipping State',
            'Shipping Zip',
            'Tax Amount',
            'Tender Type',
            'Time',
            'Type'
        ),
        'sortBy' => 'Transaction ID',
        'sortOrder' => 'Ascending',
        'transMode' => 'Live',
        'Download' => '1',
        'downloadMode' => 'asciiHeaders',
        'subaction' => 'download',
        'oldTemplateName' => '',
        'reportName' => 'CustomReport',
        'reportType' => 'CustomReport',
    )
);
```

And this is the output of $downloadpost:

```
newTemplateName=&dateRange=Custom&fromMonth=2&fromDate=10&fromYear=2015&fromHour=00&fromMinute=00&fromSecond=00&toMonth=05&toDate=10&toYear=2015&toHour=23&toMinute=59&toSecond=59&timezone=U.S.+Eastern&cardTypes=C-5%2CC-4%2CC-2%2CC-1%2CC-0&transactionTypes=S%2CD%2CO%2CA%2CF%2CC%2CV&userName=MyUserName&minAmount=0.00&maxAmount=10000.00&resultOption=Approvals+Only&displayColumns%5B0%5D=Transaction+ID&displayColumns%5B1%5D=ABA+Routing+Number&displayColumns%5B2%5D=AVS+Streeth+Match&displayColumns%5B3%5D=AVS+Zip+Match&displayColumns%5B4%5D=Account+Number&displayColumns%5B5%5D=Amount&displayColumns%5B6%5D=Authcode&displayColumns%5B7%5D=Batch+ID&displayColumns%5B8%5D=Billing+Address&displayColumns%5B9%5D=Billing+City&displayColumns%5B10%5D=Billing+Company+Name&displayColumns%5B11%5D=Billing+Country&displayColumns%5B12%5D=Billing+Email&displayColumns%5B13%5D=Billing+First+Name&displayColumns%5B14%5D=Billing+Last+Name&displayColumns%5B15%5D=Billing+State&displayColumns%5B16%5D=Billing+Zip&displayColumns%5B17%5D=CSC+Match&displayColumns%5B18%5D=Comment1&displayColumns%5B19%5D=Comment2&displayColumns%5B20%5D=Customer+Code&displayColumns%5B21%5D=Duty+Amount&displayColumns%5B22%5D=Expires&displayColumns%5B23%5D=Freight+Amount&displayColumns%5B24%5D=Invoice+Number&displayColumns%5B25%5D=Original+Transaction+ID&displayColumns%5B26%5D=PayPal+Email+ID&displayColumns%5B27%5D=PayPal+Fees&displayColumns%5B28%5D=Purchase+Order&displayColumns%5B29%5D=Response+Msg&displayColumns%5B30%5D=Result+Code&displayColumns%5B31%5D=Shipping+Address&displayColumns%5B32%5D=Shipping+City&displayColumns%5B33%5D=Shipping+Email&displayColumns%5B34%5D=Shipping+First+Name&displayColumns%5B35%5D=Shipping+Last+Name&displayColumns%5B36%5D=Shipping+State&displayColumns%5B37%5D=Shipping+Zip&displayColumns%5B38%5D=Tax+Amount&displayColumns%5B39%5D=Tender+Type&displayColumns%5B40%5D=Time&displayColumns%5B41%5D=Type&sortBy=Transaction+ID&sortOrder=Ascending&transMode=Live&Download=1&downloadMode=asciiHeaders&subaction=download&oldTemplateName=&reportName=CustomReport&reportType=CustomReport
```

The idea is to create a report with the options shown and then download it to a text file (.tsv) on my server. The only thing that is being downloaded to my text file is a failure page (Due to potential security concerns, we have logged you out... Please click here to login again).

That's my problem. So, my question is how can I create the query in a way that will work, or rewrite this one?

All of the variables, options, field names, urls, etc. are correct. I've quadruple checked them. The problem is the url encoding (I'm guessing). I've tried urldecode(), urlencode(), htmlentities(), rawurlencode(),rawurldecode(), but I don't really know what I'm doing on that score. This code used to work fine about 4 years ago. Now I'm trying to revive it, but to no avail.

I've already reached out to the support team at the site in question, but I haven't heard back yet. I don't know if they will be able to help me, so I thought I'd try here, too.

Any ideas? Is this the correct way to build a query like this? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this is perl code? Best to add a `perl` tag. In any case, have you to tried to get a "hello world" query to work against that site? Without a URL and credentials to log in we won't have anyway of trying to duplicate your problem, so having 60 lines of code doesn't help others to debug your problem. Make it small. Good luck.

Comment: No, actually it's php, not perl. Yes, I've tried creating a very simple query without the arrays, but no luck. Anyway, I just thought maybe I was making some glaring mistake with the way I was building the query, but I was told that the site in question would rather I use their xml api for this task, so I'll probably just have to scrap this whole thing.

Comment: at least change one of your tags to `php`, then you'll have the thousands of users that watch php questions looking at your question. (note that there are only 19 followers for `query-string`). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are still connect when sending the second post data ? You should take a look about cookies session with libcurl ;)